# Algorithm to calculate each node of a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

So i've been learning about decision trees and stuff, i've been googling a lot to find a way to calculate terminal nodes of a tree.

Let me explain

I need to find a way, maybe using vectors or i don't know, i have this tree:

```
              |-----6-------
             4|     
  |---2-------|------7------
  |
  |
1 |     
  |                        |------11------
  |           |-----8----10|------12------
  |-----3---5 |
              |------9-------
```

This tree can be of whatever size, i need to find each value of each node.. i.e

```
node 4 = 6+7
node 5 = 8+9
node 10 = 11+12
```

Is there any algorithm for this?

Comment: So a node's value is equivalent to the value of its left child + value of its right child? And the tree may be infinite?

Comment: If the tree is infinite then you cannot calculate a value (well... it would be infinity). Or use Haskell.

Comment: Seriously, though, if your decision tree is infinite you might be interested in learning about heuristic methods (like reinforcement learning) to take a stab at the value of that branch.

Comment: By "infinite", do you mean, the tree can be whatever size you specify, with no hard limit? A better phrasing might be, a tree of arbitrary size.

Comment: yes, that's what i mean, sorry my english is not perfect..
That's it, the tree can be whatever size...

Comment: In your example, are 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12 also nodes, or are they something else (such as edge labels or edge weights)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Populate a list of nodes with root
While there are nodes left to process
    Take next node (call it `N`) to process from list
    For each immediade child node (call it `n`) of `N`
        Add `n` to end of node list
        Add the value associated with `n` to a running total value for `N`
    Record total for `N`
    Mark `N` as processed
```

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is called [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). If should consider the [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), if the tree is too deep.